# Can a bump form be exact?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

My definition of bump form is:

> An $n$-form $\omega = f dx^1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^n$ on an $n$-dimensional smooth manifold $M$ is a bump form if it is compactly supported on a coordinate domain $(U_i, \varphi_i)$ and if $\left | \int_U \omega \right | = \pm 1$.

Now, when we consider the compactly supported cohomology $H_c^n(M)$, we know that if two compactly supported forms are cohomologous, then they have the same integral. That is because two cohomologous $n$-forms differ by an exact $(n-1)$-form (still compactly supported), and we can use Stokes' theorem to prove the claim.

In my lectures, in order to prove that the top degree cohomology of some manifold is trivial we proved that there exists a bump form in the manifold cohomologous to the $0$-form. Then the claim follows because any $n$-form can be written as a sum of bump forms, and any two bump forms in the manifold are cohomologous up to a sign.

**My question is**: how can a bump form be cohomologous to the $0$-form? If they were cohomologous, they would have the same integral! What am I missing?

My thoughts are: maybe the proof of the last claim is by contradiction? i.e. we are proving that there is no bump form in the manifold, otherwise such a bump form would be cohomologous to $0$. And that would be a contradiction. However, this line of reasoning didn't convince me.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$, every $n$-form is cohomologous to the zero form by the Poincaré lemma, even bump forms! The point is that if the integral of $\omega=du$ is nonzero, then $u$ cannot have compact support.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you! So the thing should be that in the proof we say that the bump form (which is compactly supported) is cohomologous to $0$ (which is also compactly supported) in the "normal" cohomology but not in the compactly supported one, right? That would solve the problem indeed.

Comment: Yes indeed. Take a bump function on $\mathbb{R}$. It is a derivative of some function, but not of a compactly supported one (i.e. the corresponding bump 1-form is exact but not is not d of any compactly supported function).

Comment: @moonknight Yes, indeed $H^n(\Bbb R^n)=0$ but $H^n_c(\Bbb R^n)=\Bbb R$ (compactly supported). This is because a bump $n$-form is the exterior derivative of an $(n-1)$-form, but not of a compactly supported $(n-1)$-form.